# referencing and storing the strong name externally for reuse

Tags: c#, strongname, assemblyinfo, internalsvisibleto

I have a lot of assemblies that have set the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) pointing one specifc  assembly within the same solution. Unfortunately the assembly that is being pointed to has a stong name, so I always have to put the same public key token over and over again into the AssemblyInfo.cs files. Since  there is no precompiler in c#, how would I ideally eliminate this redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of easy-ish options:

1. Use a constant instead of a literal in your AssemblyInfo.cs files.
2. Add this attribute to a shared file (e.g.: CommonFriendAssemblies.cs) that is linked rather than copied into your individual projects.

#1 is somewhat simpler to manage, but it has the unfortunate side-effect of [removing IntelliSense support for the referenced internals in the referencing project](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542121/intellisense-warns-red-sqiggle-incorrectly-for-internalsvisibleattribute-set-by-a-constant).

#2 is somewhat more complex to manage, but it doesn't interfere with IntelliSense support.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use t4

rename `AssemblyInfo.cs` to `AssemblyInfo.tt`

and add something like this

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" hostspecific="True" debug="True" #>
<#@ output extension="cs" #>

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("<# Write(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName); #>")]
```